# Core data: background fetching

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data

I've read tons of similar question, but looks like there is no answer.

I have a background thread, that fetches data.

```
// bg queue
let context = // private context with NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType
users = Model.MR_findAllSortedBy("username", ascending: true, inContext: context) as! [Model]
```

I want to reload tableView in main thread  with [Model] array. 
If I pass `users` directly to main thread it will lead to undefined behaviour (according to CD docs).

On other hand I have 2 options:

1. fetch objects on main context (which leads to UI blocks)
2. pass objectId which leads to object unfaulting (which leads to UI blocks)

What is the correct way to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

The best setup is to use a table view with a `NSFetchedResultsController` (also very handy with Magical Record) and implement the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` which will update the table automatically.

Just fetching all and sorting will be easily done on the main thread (FRC will optimize and only fetch what the table view needs to display). That means your assumption about option 1. is not correct.

```
do { fetchedResultsController.performFetch() } catch {}
tableView.reloadData()
```

is all you need.

Comment: are there any other way except NSfetchedResultController?

Comment: You don't want another setup. The FRC helps you fetch as little as possible, thus *avoiding* massive DB searches which are the very thing that would make background fetching necessary in the first place. To do the optimizations yourself by hand would be insanely difficult.

Comment: That being said, you *can* do it, but should not, unless you have a compelling reason to need it. I don't see any.

Comment: Let's say I need to make a pagination and fetch data from server first and only then pass it to FRC

Comment: **That** you **would** do in the background, but **without** passing the objects to some main thread array. Just `save()`, pushing the changes up to the parent context on the main thread, and the FRC will take care of the rest.